# How is the parameter "weight" (DMatrix) used in the gradient boosting procedure (xgboost)?

Tags: xgboost

In xgboost it is possible to set the parameter `weight` for a `DMatrix`. This is apparently a list of weights wherein each value is a weight for a corresponding sample. 
I can't find any information on how these weights are actually used in the gradient boosting procedure. Are they related to `eta` ?

For example, if I would set `weight` to 0.3 for all samples and `eta` to 1, would this be the same as setting `eta` to 0.3 and `weight` to 1?

Comment: the docs are really lacking on this but I have been using instance weights gently a little bit and dug up a few links.. good question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`xgboost` allows for instance weighting during the construction of the `DMatrix`, as you noted.   This weight is directly tied the instance and travels with it throughout the entire training.  Thus it is included in the calculations of the gradients and hessians, **and directly impacts the split points and traing of an `xgboost` model.**

see [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/input_format.md) and [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/144)

> Instance Weight File
>
> XGBoost supports providing each instance an weight to differentiate
>   the importance of instances. For example, if we provide an instance
>   weight file for the "train.txt" file in the example as below:
>
> train.txt.weight
>
> 1
>
> 0.5
>
> 0.5
>
> 1
>
> 0.5
>
> It means that XGBoost will emphasize more on the first and fourth instance， that is to say positive instances while training. The
>   configuration is similar to configuring the group information. If the
>   instance file name is "xxx", XGBoost will check whether there is a
>   file named "xxx.weight" in the same directory and if there is, will
>   use the weights while training models.

**It is very different from** `eta`

`eta` simply tells `xgboost` how much the blend the last tree trained into the ensemble. A measure of how greedy the ensemble should be at each iteration.

> For example, if I would set `weight` to 0.3 for all samples and `eta`
>   to 1, would this be the same as setting `eta` to 0.3 and `weight` to
>   1?

- A constant `weight` of 1 for all instances is the default, so changing that to a constant of .3 for all instances would still be equal weighting, so this shouldn't impact things too much. However, setting `eta` up to 1, from .3, would make the training much more aggressive.

Comment: When you say _This weight is directly tied the instance and travels with it throughout the entire training_ what do you mean in detail? Is there any reference to better understand how the weights impact the training procedure?

Comment: do weights have to be between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

`weight` in [xgboost's `DMatrix`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core) is the only correct way to enter *[exposure variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#%22Exposure%22_and_offset)* (e.g. insurance policy duration) for Poisson-distributed targets, e.g. insurance claims frequency (i.e. when `'objective': 'count:poisson'`).

*More info*

So what are the incorrect ways? Contrary to replies on Stack Exchange, `base_margin` and `set_base_margin`. I benchmarked all these three options against GLM's `sample_weight` (exposed by `PoissonRegressor`'s `fit` method), and only `weight` produced similarly unbiased models (as seen from actual vs. predicted plots for individual features). Not to mention the early stopping metrics (Poisson negative log-likehood or RMSE) being markedly improved (lower) by switching to `weight` (down to the level that improves over GLM).

Comment: Thanks! that's very interesting! considering I'm using the exposure in the XGB weights (as you suggested). How should I use the weights to emphasize the frequency? 
I calculated weights based on my dataset's occurrence rate ( e.g claims rate in the past year) Do you have an idea for how to use those weights given I'm using the sample weights for the exposure (which makes a lot of sense)?