# adjust weights for predicted classes in xgboost in loss function

Tags: xgboost

Is it possible to adjust the weighted error for a given target? What Im trying to do is weight the loss higher for rarer classes when predicting multi-classes.

Answer (score 1):

If using the core data structure you can set the weight of labels through the "set_weight" parameter:

> set_weight(weight) Set weight of each instance.
>
> Parameters:   weight (array like) – Weight for each data point

While documentation is quite lackluster on that topic, i have found a reasonable answer that might be useful on this previous topic: [How is the parameter "weight" (DMatrix) used in the gradient boosting procedure (xgboost)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983565/how-is-the-parameter-weight-dmatrix-used-in-the-gradient-boosting-procedure)

quoting it:

> Instance Weight File
>
> XGBoost supports providing each instance an weight to differentiate
>   the importance of instances. For example, if we provide an instance
>   weight file for the "train.txt" file in the example as below:
>
> train.txt.weight
>
> 1
>
> 0.5
>
> 0.5
>
> 1
>
> 0.5
>
> It means that XGBoost will emphasize more on the first and fourth
>   instance， that is to say positive instances while training. The
>   configuration is similar to configuring the group information. If the
>   instance file name is "xxx", XGBoost will check whether there is a
>   file named "xxx.weight" in the same directory and if there is, will
>   use the weights while training models.

hope it helps!

Comment: My understanding is this is for tree instances not so much for the actual classes themselves.