# How to set weights in multi-class classification in xgboost for imbalanced data?

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification

I know that you can set scale_pos_weight for an imbalanced dataset. However, How to deal with the multi-classification problem in the imbalanced dataset. I have gone through https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost/18823 but don't quite understand how to set weight parameter in Dmatrix.

Can anyone please explain in detail?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983565/how-is-the-parameter-weight-dmatrix-used-in-the-gradient-boosting-procedure and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618491/adjust-weights-for-predicted-classes-in-xgboost-in-loss-function

Answer (score 5):

For imbalanced dataset, I used the "weights" parameter in Xgboost where weights is an array of weight assigned according to the class the data belongs to.

```py
def CreateBalancedSampleWeights(y_train, largest_class_weight_coef):
    classes = np.unique(y_train, axis = 0)
    classes.sort()
    class_samples = np.bincount(y_train)
    total_samples = class_samples.sum()
    n_classes = len(class_samples)
    weights = total_samples / (n_classes * class_samples * 1.0)
    class_weight_dict = {key : value for (key, value) in zip(classes, weights)}
    class_weight_dict[classes[1]] = class_weight_dict[classes[1]] * 
    largest_class_weight_coef
    sample_weights = [class_weight_dict[y] for y in y_train]
    return sample_weights
```

Just pass the target column and the occurance rate of most frequent class (if most frequent class has 75 out of 100 samples,  then its 0.75)

```py
    largest_class_weight_coef = 
    max(df_copy['Category'].value_counts().values)/df.shape[0]
    
    #pass y_train as numpy array
    weight = CreateBalancedSampleWeights(y_train, largest_class_weight_coef)

    #And then use it like this
    xg = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=1000, weights = weight, max_depth=20)
```

Thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

`XGBClassifier` request **don't support** `weights` parameter

Please, use `sample_weight` in `fit()` request: `fit(X, y, sample_weight)`

For detail information please [xgboost python api](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn)

For use `weight` in direct request use another algo: **random forest** or **light gbm**